# Change the background color of the list (AlertDialog) when selecting an option, and keep it on open again

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have questions about how to do a custom alertdialog
Where It change its background when I selected It, and if I select another item, the new one change its background and the before return its normal background.

```
String[] list = {"1","2","3","4","5"}

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity_main_panel.this);
    builder.setTitle("tittle");
    builder.setItems(list, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancelar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });


AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

Image about what i want:
first select

[image]

second select

[image]

Comment: Piece of code added by you is not of recycler view Adapter.

Comment: edited, remove comment.

Comment: put your recycler view code

Comment: I made a mistake in the title and tags, it is only a alertDialog, change background on selected, option and keep it on reopening

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking string array create one model class for row items and take one variable lets say isSelected and in onBindViewHolder method do it like this

```
       if(obj.isSelected) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(yellow) }
        else {
            view.setBackgroundColor(transparent)
```

and onItemClick set that position selected true and others selected false and then notify the adapter.

Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just run into the same problem. I fix it by using `setAdapter()` instead of `setItems()`, and you can custom your adapter to set background color.
For example, if you use `ArrayAdapter`, you can override `getView()` to custom you requirement, setting background color.